# How to show only values in a column and ignore the blank cells in Access query?

Tags: sql, ms-access, where-clause, sql-null

I have a column that has a primary key and then a column that has values in some of them. How do I get the query to show the values in those columns only?

I have tried the following and keep getting errors:

SELECT [Case Level Report].[Charge Level] WHERE not [Case Level Report].[Charge Level] is null
FROM [Case Level Report];

I also tried:
SELECT [Case Level Report].[Charge Level] WHERE is not null <> ''
FROM [Case Level Report];

and

SELECT [Case Level Report].[Charge Level] WHERE is not null
FROM [Case Level Report];

I'm lost and cant figure it out now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want an `IS NOT NULL` condition in a `WHERE` clause. The syntax is:

```
SELECT [Charge Level]
FROM [Case Level Report]
WHERE [Charge Level] IS NOT NULL
```